# Новомодный оборот

Tags: пунктуация

Сейчас есть новомодный оборот из серии "что-то такое что-то". Причем, в этот обороте не ставят никаких знаков препинания. У меня в блоге достаточно взрослый и грамотный человек написал: "Европа такая Европа". Мне кажется, что в этом обороте после первого слова должо ставиться тире, а в конце двоеточие. Я прав?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы написал с одной запятой, после первой Европы. Что касается двоеточия, то без контекста сказать ничего нельзя.
Впрочем, я вообще не очень понимаю смысл, может и предлагаемая запятая - так сказать "контекстно-зависимая".

Answer (score 0):

Я бы тут тире поставил. Так и напрашивается "это". А в конце никакого двоеточия, если это конец предложения.